# Is it possible to define instances in the RDFS file?

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, ontology, rdfs

[image]

for example, could we say in the RDFS SW is thought by MZ
IF yes what is the correct syntax to do it

I appreciate your help

Comment: why not? RDFS is still written as RDF triples, everything is an RDF triple, just add the RDF triple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RDFS is essentially just a pre-defined set of RDF resources (such as `rdfs:Class`, `rdfs:subClassOf`, etc.). In other words, an RDF Schema is *itself* just an RDF model. There is nothing to stop you from putting the RDF Schema and the instance data of your RDF model in the same file. It's all triples.

RDF(S) is an abstract model and has no requirements about *where* the information is stored, or in what order. So you can first define all your instance data, then add the RDFS data, or the other way around, or even mixed up. It can all be in one file, or split over two or more, whatever you want.

Of course, to keep things readable for yourself it may be easier to define the schema data first and the instances later, and possibly also to split the schema and instance data into separate files, but you don't *have* to if you don't want to.